# Is there any economic history book on how western economy coped with the fall of roman empire?

Tags: reference-request, economic-history

I recently finished Tamin's The Roman Market Economy. The book describes how Roman Republic and later Roman Empire created an integrated and at the time developed European economy. I enjoyed it a lot, the book however does not discuss much the discusses how it all fell apart after fifth century. Is there some good economic history book that explores this time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jones' *The Later Roman Empire, 284-602: A Social, Economic and Administrative Survey*, although rather dated (1964), appears to be a major scholarly work on this topic (I haven't read it but recall it being mentioned by a historian colleague).  [This review](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.2307/2856118) explains that it was published by two different publishers, one in two volumes and one in three, and [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-roman-studies/article/abs/h-m-jones-the-later-roman-empire-284602-a-social-economic-and-administrative-survey-3-vols-oxford-basil-blackwell-1964-pp-xxvi-1522-vi-5231068-vi-448-with-7-maps-in-folder-14-14s/9737844A0495DF6C06D9AB9E383D4C3A) explains some limitations in its scholarship. It appears to be out of print but second-hand and library copies are available and one volume can be accessed via [Scribd](https://www.scribd.com/document/510449880/A-H-M-Jones-The-Later-Roman-Empire-284-602-a-Social-Economic-and-Administrative-Survey-Vol-1).